# Background a un componente de angular

Tags: css3, bootstrap-4, angular7

tengo un proyecto en angular con bootstrap, en donde tengo un componente login, como es que puedo colocarle a este componente un fondo de color. Intente hacer lo siguiente dentro del archivo login.component.html:

```
<div style="background-color: black;width:1920px; height:1020px;">
  <div class="container text-center">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp"
              placeholder="Usuario">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Contraseña">
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Entrar</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Sin embargo, en el navegador no abarca toda la pantalla, muestra solo una franja delgada de color blanco.

Comment: Ponle el estilo al <body>. En este caso solo estas pintando el divisor.

Comment: Si usas Angular, usa la hoja de estilo del componente, es lo más adecuado. Evita poner el estilo en línea en la plantilla `html` como lo estás haciendo. Saludos

Comment: Cada componente de Angular, tiene sus propias hojas de estilos, puedes identificar el archivo con la extensión `.sccs` ahí solo tienes que aplicar un `body { background-color: black; }` y listo.

Answer (score 1):

```
*,
*:before,
*::after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

y en el Background que no toma todo el ancho usa "height: 100vh" eso significa que usara todo el ancho y alto disponible